# Пофиксить ошибку Last packet sent to the server was 28 ms ago

Tags: java, hibernate

Имеется игровой сервер, который использует hibernate для работы с базой данных, спустя n-времени, сервер просто выдает такую ошибку:

```
    18/09/02 12:21:29 WARN spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
    18/09/02 12:21:29 ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper: Communications link failure
Last packet sent to the server was 28 ms ago.
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2031)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1832)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1247)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:905)...
```

Далее, после этой ошибки, если сделать любое действие в данном потоке\сессии связанное с бд, 
вылазит данная ошибка:

```
    org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:152)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1395)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)...
```

hibnernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://*.*.*.*:*/*?autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>   
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depths">0</property>
```

Comment: Предполагаю что бд не выдержала нагрузки (зная как хибер грузит бд) и просто схлопнулась. И теперь подключения к ней нет.

Comment: @Tsyklop данная ошибка появляется и без нагрузки, сервер стоит в афк минут 10, заходит игрок после рестарта, и вылазит она. Думаю проблема не в нагрузке

Comment: может не закрываете соединение к бд?

Comment: @Tsyklop закрываю